# Issue with react component and gatsby JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, gatsby, gatsby-plugin

I am trying to create a portfolio website using Gatsby js and I am trying to use the card component from the gatsby-plugin-material-ui package. I have the card in a separate file in my components folder and I export it for use in my actual project page file. When I load up the website on localhost everything loads up fine except for when I hit the project button to navigate to the project page. Once I try to access the page I get this error

**Error in function createFiberFromTypeAndProps in ./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:25058**

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports. Check the render method of `Cards`.

Here is the code where I create and export the component

```
import * as React from "react"
import Card from 'gatsby-plugin-material-ui';
import CardContent from 'gatsby-plugin-material-ui';
import CardMedia from 'gatsby-plugin-material-ui';
import Typography from 'gatsby-plugin-material-ui';
import { CardActionArea } from 'gatsby-plugin-material-ui'

const Cards = () => {

    return (
        <div className="cardsTest">
            <Card sx={{ maxWidth: 345 }}>
                <CardActionArea>
                    <CardMedia
                        component="img"
                        height="140"
                        image="../images/space.jpg"
                        alt="Gagan Toronto"
                    /> 
                        <CardContent>
                            <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="div">
                                Space Card
                            </Typography>
                            <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
                                This is just a placeholder card 
                            </Typography>
                        </CardContent>
                </CardActionArea>
            </Card>    
         </div>
    )

}

export default Cards
```

and here is the code where I import the component to use for my project page

```
import * as React from "react"

//components used across site
import Header from "../components/header"
import Cards from "../components/Cards"

const ProjectPage = () => (
    <div>
    <Header />
    <Cards />
    </div>
  )

export default ProjectPage;
```

I feel like its a problem with how I am exporting the component but I am not sure what it is, any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

> I feel like its a problem with how I am exporting the component but I
> am not sure what it is, any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Indeed, it seems that some of your imports of `Cards` component are wrong. I assume that the one that is causing the issue is `CardActionArea` but it would be nice if you can detect which one is by commenting them all and importing one by one.

I'd try importing like:

```
import CardActionArea from 'gatsby-plugin-material-ui'
```